# how to play many video files continuously in html

Tags: javascript, html

I have many some video files. And I want to play these video files continuously.
So While one play, I load next video file.
And when current video is ended I play next video and so on. But when run next video, screen does not run continuously. How to improve this.
This is my code.

-HTML

```
  <button onclick="playVid()" type="button">Play Video</button>
  <button onclick="pauseVid(this)" type="button">Pause/Resume</button><br> 
  <video class="currentVideo" width="640" height="360" hidden>
     <source src="" type="video/mp4">
     Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
  </video>

  <video class="prevVideo" width="640" height="360" hidden>
    <source src="" type="video/mp4">
    Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
 </video>

  <div>
    <canvas id="myCanvas" width="640" height="360" />
  </div>
```

-javascript

```
    var index = 2
    var vidcurrent = document.getElementsByClassName("currentVideo")[0];
    path = "./video/1.mp4";
    vidcurrent.src= path;
    vidcurrent.load();
    var next= false;
    function playVid() {
      vidcurrent = document.getElementsByClassName("currentVideo")[0];
      prevvideo = document.getElementsByClassName("prevVideo")[0];
      next = false;
      loadNextvideo();
      vidcurrent.play();
      vidcurrent.onplay = function () {
        timerID = window.setInterval(function () {
          drawImage(vidcurrent);
        }, 30);
      };
      vidcurrent.onended = function() {
        vidcurrent.className="prevVideo";
        console.log(vidcurrent.className);
        prevvideo.className="currentVideo";
        index ++;
        playVid();
      };
    }

    function loadNextvideo()
    {
      var prevvideo = document.getElementsByClassName("prevVideo")[0];
      path = "./video/" + index + ".mp4";
      var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
      http.open("GET", path);      
      http.send();
      http.onload = function() {
        if (this.status === 200) {
            prevvideo.src = path
            console.log(path + "File exists");
            prev = true;         
        } else { 
            console.log(path +" File doesn't exists");
        }
      };      
      if(!prev)
      {
        setTimeout(loadNextvideo, 3000);
      }      
    }   
    function drawImage(vid) {
      var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
      var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
      ctx.drawImage(vid, 0, 0, 640, 360);
    }
```

Comment: what on earth does "the screen is slightly hardened" mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should load video to src.
If not while the video tag load src from url, you can't play video. So try like this in ajax.

```
     http.onload = function() {
        if (this.status === 200) {
          var reader = new FileReader();
          reader.onloadend = function() {
  
            var byteCharacters = atob(reader.result.slice(reader.result.indexOf(',') + 1));
            
            var byteNumbers = new Array(byteCharacters.length);

            for (var i = 0; i < byteCharacters.length; i++) {
              
              byteNumbers[i] = byteCharacters.charCodeAt(i);
              
            }

            var byteArray = new Uint8Array(byteNumbers);
            var blob = new Blob([byteArray], {type: 'video/ogg'});
            var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
            prevvideo.src = url
         
            console.log(path + "File exists");
            prev = true;
          }
          reader.readAsDataURL(http.response);
         
      } else { 
          console.log(path +" File doesn't exists");
        }
      };
```